# regex for exact number of colon separated fields

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I am searching for an regex which would match exactly 7 occurences of the .*: (7 fields colon separated)

unfortunatelly, what I combined:

```
grep -E '(.*:){7}' ...
```

does also print the same lines when I decrase number in {}.
how to test it for fixed exactly 7 occurences?

Comment: Instead of using `.*` use `[^:]*`

Comment: Try `^([^:]*:){7}[^:]*$`

Comment: Can a field contain a quoted or escaped colon?

Comment: @DonJ, Please post samples of input and output in CODE TAGS in your post.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew glenn didn't properly tag you, but he's right.

Comment: @ctwheels OP is not consistent anyway: *exactly 7 occurences of the `.*:` (7 fields colon separated)* - 7 `.*:`s means there are 8 fields.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew fair enough, the OP should clarify.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thank you. ^([^:]*:){7}[^:]*$ works as expected.

Comment: Maybe  awk is still  a better idea?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem statement "match 7 colon separated fields" is a good fit for awk:

```
awk -F: 'NF == 7' file ...
```

Comment: Should be `awk -F: 'NF == 8' file` if OP wants to match exact 7 colons

Comment: Maybe. The question is ambiguous. We obviously need to see some input text.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you still want to use `grep` to solve the problem:

```
grep -E '^([^:]*:){7}[^:]*$' file
```

**Details**:

- `^` - start of line
- `([^:]*:){7}` - exactly 7 occurrences of

  - `[^:]*` - zero or more chars other than `:`
  - `:` - a colon
- `[^:]*` - zero or more chars other than `:`
- `$` - end of line.

See an [online demo of the regex](https://regex101.com/r/A7gRPe/1) (*do not rely on this service to check `grep` patterns validity!*)